# Xamarin Mobile offline DB sync with SQL Server on-premise

Tags: xamarin, azure-app-service-envrmnt, zumero

Is there a way to sync a SQLite mobile offline DB with an on premise SQL Server? As far as I understand, Azure offline sync syncs with Table storage and not SQL server. Also, hybrid connection and hybrid connection manager doesn't take care of synchronization/replication as far as I know.Could anyone of you confirm whether there is a way to achieve this?

Came across something called Zumero, but not sure how much it is practifcally possible.

Comment: This is *exactly* what Zumero does. This question is likely to be closed soon as tool recommendations are off-topic here, but please email support@zumero.com if you have questions about Zumero's suitability for your situation.